# Putting contents of a .txt file into a List in

Tags: c#, list, generics, io

I have a .txt file that looks something like this:

```
1,Bob,Male //first row

2,Jim,Male //second row

3,Mary,Female //third row
```

I want to put these items into a generic list in c#, storing each column into something as "Id", "Name", "Gender" and treating each row as a different item of the list.

How would I go about doing this? I have no idea where to even start. I've looked at I/O operations and understand how to access a file, but I don't know how to create a variable name for each column and store each row as a new entry.

Comment: Don't you know how to design a class..?

Comment: yes but that is not my question

Comment: But in your question you said: **I want to put these items into a generic list in c#, storing each column into something as "Id", "Name", "Gender" and treating each row as a different item of the list.**...

Comment: You don't know `string` methods like `split` too? :\ç

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should show some effort and a sample code before asking for a complete solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create Class which will represent your data. Lets call it `Person`
   Person will have 3 properties `ID(int)`, `Gender(string)`, `Name(string)`
2. Create `List<Person> listOfPerson = new List<Person>()`;
3. Read the file line by line using loop -> Check `File.ReadLines` method
4. Create new instance of the class in the loop `Person person = new Person();`
5. Take the line from the file, call `string.Split(',');`
6. Set person properties from the `string[]` which you create with splitting `p.ID = arr[0]` and so on
7. Add the Person class to the `List<Person>`

I answer you with text so you should try something by yourself and learn how to do it in the future !

Comment: `ReadLine` of what class? BTW I voted to close this Q&A. SO isn't a coding service where you ask for a complete solution from a given problem... OP should show some effort before asking here...

Comment: Haha I just noticed we have the exact same answer

Comment: thank you mybirthname, i remember doing something similar to this with java i just couldnt remember how to do it!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer you are right, I miss the s of ReadLines. He said he know how to read file, so I suppose he knows about File.ReadLines. Again I agree this question probably should be closed for too broad.

Comment: @user127815 you are welcome you can accept the question if helped you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a class (maybe called Record) with three properties: Id, Name and Sex
2. Read the contents from the file using File.ReadLines method as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Now you have a list of all the rows in your file. You need to loop through the items in the array and split them using String.Split method as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx).
4. The splitted array will contain id at index 0, name at index 1 and sex at index 2. Create a new instance of the class you created in step 1 and assign these values to the properties.

Create a generic list to hold your instances of the Record class.